# Undo keyless ssh access

Tags: ssh

Because I access a server a lot, I did the `ssh-copy-id` operation and added the server I used to it. I want to undo this operation as it's not letting me do things I was used to doing.

How do I undo an `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 2):

To view your RSA key, type this command on your source Linux

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

In your remote host, remove the line with your RSA Key from the file `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.